# Almacenar un ID obtenido de Volley y PHP desde MySQL con sharedPrerences / Android Studio

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, android-volley

Buen día, tengo una consulta tengo una aplicación la cual al inicio obtiene varios tipos de negocios o empresas esto no es nada del otro mundo solo hago una petición con `volley` hacia una base de datos `MySQL` y con `PHP` obtengo en un `RecyclerView` todas las empresas registradas en una tabla, al momento de seleccionar alguna empresa o negocio obtengo su **id** de negocio de acuerdo a ese **id** me muestra la información de la empresa seleccionada, hasta aquí todo bien ahora lo que necesito es que la pantalla que aparecía al principio que en este caso es la de obtener los negocios registrados solo se me muestre la primer vez que inicie la aplicación luego que inicie directamente a la pantalla inicial de la empresa que se selecciono, esto tengo entendido que lo podría lograr con `shredPreferences` lo que trato de hacer es guardar el **id** de negocio que se selecciono al inicio y luego obtenerlo con **getSharedPreferences** para posteriormente pasarlo como parámetro al método donde obtengo la información de la empresa en este caso seria al `if`, tratare de explicar de manera gráfica el problema para que sea un poco mas entendible.

Como primer paso creo la clase **obtenerNegocios** la cual luciría así:

```
RecyclerView rvLista;
ArrayList<Negocios> negocios;
AdaptadorNegocios adaptador;
String URL_NEGOCIOS = "";
public static int idNegocio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.obtener_negocios);

    boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

    if (isFirstRun) {
        obtenerNegocios();
    } else{
        startActivity(new Intent(ObtenerNegocios.this, SplashPrincipal.class));
    }

    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();

    negocios = new ArrayList<>();
    rvLista = findViewById(R.id.rvListaNegocios);
    rvLista.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

    obtenerNegocios();    

}

public void obtenerNegocios() {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Por favor espera...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    URL_NEGOCIOS = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas3/obtenerNegocios.php";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_NEGOCIOS,

            response -> {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Negocios");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        negocios.add(
                                new Negocios(

                                        jsonObject1.getString("nombre_negocio"),
                                        jsonObject1.getString("img_negocio"),
                                        idNegocio = jsonObject1.getInt("id_negocio")));

                    }

                    adaptador = new AdaptadorNegocios(this, negocios);
                    rvLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace
    ) {
    };

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT * 2,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

Primeramente declaro una variable estática **idNegocio** esta variable me sirve para obtenerla al presionar seleccionar la empresa:

```
public static int idNegocio;
```

Por cierto esta seria la variable que guardaría en `sharedPreferences`

Siguiendo en el `onCreate` tenemos un pequeño codigo para validar si ya se ingreso una vez a la pantalla si es asi que siga al activity principal de la empresa que se selecciono:

```
boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

if (isFirstRun) {
    obtenerNegocios();
} else{
    startActivity(new Intent(ObtenerNegocios.this, SplashPrincipal.class));
}

getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();
```

Por ultimo el metodo que llamamos en el oncreate `obtenerNegocios();` simplemente es la peticion al servidor para que nos ebtenga lops negocios o empresas registradas, algo que vale la pena recalcar es que dentro del `for` tenemos:

```
idNegocio = jsonObject1.getInt("id_negocio")));
```

La variable **idNegocio** es igual al id de negocio que obtuvimos de la base de datos.

Entonces hasta aqui ya he explicado toda la logica que realizo al momento de obtener los negocios o empresas en mi pantalla principal, ahora lo que necesito es que dependiendo del id de negocio que se seleccione ese id quede guardado cuando se inicie nuevamente la aplicacion y asi obtenga los datos del negocio que se selecciono.

Naturalmente cuando lo selecciono viajo al Splash Principal del negocio que se selecciono, entonces la logica aplicada en la pantalla **SplashPrincipal.class** es la siguiente:

Dentro de la clase tengo un metodo llamado DatosEmpresa() esto me sirve para obtener los datos de la empresa o negocio que se selecciono en la pantalla inicial:

```
public void DatosEmpresa(){

    if (ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio == 1){
        String URL = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas/obtenerEmpresa.php";
        System.out.println(URL);

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SplashPrincipal.this);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,

                response -> {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Empresa");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            gNombreEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("nombre_empresa");
                            tvEmpresa.setText(gNombreEmpresa);

                            gCorreoEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("correo_empresa");

                            gLogoEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("logo_empresa");
                            Glide.with(this).load(gLogoEmpresa).into(imgEmpresa);

                            gFacebookEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("facebook_empresa");

                            gAnimacionEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("animacion_empresa");
                            Glide.with(this).load(gAnimacionEmpresa).into(animacionEmpresa);

                            gRedEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("red");
                            gGreenEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("green");
                            gBlueEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("blue");

                            tvEmpresa.setTextColor(Color.rgb(gRedEmpresa, gGreenEmpresa, gBlueEmpresa));

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                , error -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {};
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
    else if (ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio == 2){

        String URL = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas2/obtenerEmpresa.php";

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SplashPrincipal.this);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,

                response -> {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Empresa");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            gNombreEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("nombre_empresa");
                            tvEmpresa.setText(gNombreEmpresa);

                            gLogoEmpresa = jsonObject1.getString("logo_empresa");
                            Glide.with(this).load(gLogoEmpresa).into(imgEmpresa);

                            gRedEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("red");
                            gGreenEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("green");
                            gBlueEmpresa = jsonObject1.getInt("blue");

                            tvEmpresa.setTextColor(Color.rgb(gRedEmpresa, gGreenEmpresa, gBlueEmpresa));

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                , error -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {};
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Aqui es igual nada del otro mundo solo obtengo los datos de la empresa con `volley` y `PHP` desde `MySQL`

Sin embargo aqui vemos algo diferente y es en la siguiente linea:

```
 if (ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio == 1){
//Obtengo la informacion del negocio 1
    } else if (ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio == 2){
//Obtengo la informacion del negocio 2
    }
```

Como lo abran notado con este simple `if` valido que id se seleccionó y dependiendo de ello obtengo la información de la empresa o negocio

Hasta aquí ya he explicado la lógica que he aplicado pero no lo que he tratado de hacer:

Regresamos al principio y nos vamos al adapter de la activity negocios:

```
negociosViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Obtener el id del negocio
            ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio = listaNegocios.get(posicion).getIdNegocio();

           //Cuando presiono en el boton de la empresa guardo el id de negocio
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = cContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("idNegocio", ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio);
            editor.apply();

            //Intencion al splash dependiendo del id del negocio
            cContext.startActivity(new Intent(cContext, SplashPrincipal.class));             

        }
    });
```

Como recalco en los comentarios al principio solo obtengo el id seleccionado del modelo luego guardo ese id con `sharedPreferences` y por ultimo hago el `intent`.

Luego en la clase del **SplashPrincipal** trato de obtener el id guardado con getSharedPreferences:

Declarando una variable global:

```
int idNegocioShared;
```

Llamando al `getSharedPreferences` desde en `onCreate`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        idNegocioShared = sharedPref.getInt("idNegocio", 0);
```

Y por último agregándolo en el if:

```
if (ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio == 1 || idNegocioShared == 1){

} else if (ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio == 2 || idNegocioShared == 2){

}
```

Pero cuando imprimo en consola el **idNegocioShared** es 0.

Por ultimo mostrare imagenes representativas de como se vereflejado el problema:

En primer lugar abro la pantalla de negocios para posteriormente seleccionar alguno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego Me muestra el **splash** con la info del negocio seleccionado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando cierro la aplicación y la vuelvo a abrir ya no me muestra la selección de negocios debido a que ya seleccione un negocio por primera vez y solo me deveria mostrar el `splash` con el **id de negocio** que guarde en **sharedPreferences** sin embargo no obtengo los datos ya que como había mencionado el **id de negocio es 0**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto seria todo, principalmente me disculpo por la exhaustiva explicación a pesar de no ser un problema muy grande pero mi poca experiencia con Android me impide hacer mejores preguntas.

Espero que la pregunta como la explicación sea entendible de lo contrario por favor ayudarme a editarla, si necesitan mas código por favor decirme, de antemano muchas gracias, Saludos!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu implementación es correcta, incluso el nombre de la preferencia es el mismo cuando guardas y obtienes el valor, debes asegurar que el valor `ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio` tenga un valor diferente a 0, puedes depurar o imprimir y revisar en el LogCat.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = cContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("idNegocio", ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio);
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, si fíjate que efectivamente cuando imprimo el valor por consola me trae el valor por defecto que es 0 no me trae el id seleccionado.

Comment: Así es, @AdielMoran , tu implementación de SharedPreferences es correcta, el problema como comento es el valor de ObtenerNegocios.idNegocio

Comment: Hola gracias, si fue error mío de administración es que me surgió otro inconveniente en mi aplicación y me gustaría solucionar primero el de cambio de base de datos y luego venir nuevamente a este.